# C# Basic Arrays: Code returning incorrect value

Tags: c#

I have two arrays of doubles. For example: {1,2,3} {4,5,6} We are using (x,y) coordinates as (1,4),(2,5) and (3,6) for example. So there are 3 data points in this example. We need to calculate the slope between all of the points and store the slope with the maximum absolute value. To do this I have a function with a 'for' loop inside a 'for' loop. My code is successfully calculating the maximum absolute value slope when I use it in the Main.

So now the final step is to store the positions that this max slope occurs at in the first array and print out the values of the same positions in the second array.

NOTE: My code is printing out the values one position before where it should be. For example, if the max slope occurs at the 4th and 5th positions, then my code prints out the 3rd and 4th positions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<double> Array1 = new List<double>();
        List<double> Array2 = new List<double>();

        Array1.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[0]));
        Array2.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[1]));


        int[] positions = GreatestSlopeLocation(Array1, Array2);

        Console.WriteLine("The Location of the max slope is {0} {1}", 
            Array2[positions[0]], Array2[positions[1]]);
    }

    static int[] GreatestSlopeLocation(List<double> x, List<double> y)
    {
        int size = x.Count;
        double maxSlope = Double.MinValue; // don't set this to 0
        // consider case when all slopes are  negative
        // 
        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                double slope = (y[j] - y[i]) / (x[j] - x[i]);
                if (slope > maxSlope) // I think you want > instead of < here
                {
                    maxSlope = slope;
                    index1 = i;
                    index2 = j;
                }
            }
        }
        return new int[]{index1, index2};
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your sample code doesn't populate the lists (not arrays, by the way - it's worth distinguishing between them and giving them appropriate names). It's much easier to help you if we can just copy, compile, run and see the problem in action.

Comment: I think using dictionaries here would make a cleaner solution.

Comment: My error, I didnt add in the population of the lists code. I have edited it in.

Comment: Now it just won't compile. Just hard-code the data, e.g. `var list1 = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 };`. It's also hard to see what you mean by "3rd and 4th" positions when your sample data only has 3 data points...

Comment: Where are the variable "columns" defined?

Comment: I believe it's just a typo - I think `slope = maxSlope;` should be `maxSlope = slope;`

Comment: When I switch the order of maxSlope and slope I get 0 and 1 printing out. These are the first 2 values in the array, not the positions I need to print out.

Comment: @user5622879: Well your code doesn't print the positions - it prints the values. If you want to print the positions, your arguments to `Console.WriteLine` should be `positions[0]` and `positions[1]`, not `Array2[positions[0]]` and `Array2[positions[1]]`... but it's very unclear what you actually want to print, given the question...

Comment: No you were right the first time I do need to print the actual values so I need Array2[positions[0]] but it does not print out the correct values it prints the values from position 1 and 2

Comment: And when I reverse the order of slope and maxSlope back to the way I originally had it then it prints out the values one position before where they should be. And I understand my data could be confusing so say in a data set with 10 data points if it is supposed to print positions 6 and 7 it prints 5 and 6 instead.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand it correctly, your current code will *always* finish with `i == size - 2, j==size - 1`... because every slope is greater than `double.MinValue`, which is the only value that `maxSlope` ever takes.

The problem is here:

```
if (slope > maxSlope)
{
    slope = maxSlope;
    index1 = i;
    index2 = j;
}
```

If you've found a new maximum slope, you remember the indexes of it... but not the slope itself. You're assigning a new value to the `slope` variable, which is never used again in that iteration. You want to remember the new maximum slope in `maxSlope`:

```
maxSlope = slope;
```